# anchor reference to <tr> tag in reStructuredText (rst)

Tags: html, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a script that automatically builds tables in rst using the simplified syntax, for example:

```
.. list-table::
      :widths: 5, 32
      :header-rows: 1

      * - Name
        - Default Value

      * - numVar
        - 515
      * - stringVar
        - "Hello World"
      * - arrayVar
        - [1,9,42,14,10,11,-1]
      * - booleanVar
        - true
      * - objectVar
        - {"keyA":"valueA","keyNum":3}
      * - nullVar
        - null
```

I want to create an external page that has anchor references to specific rows, so when the user clicks it, it scrolls down to the correct row. For example:

```
 <a href="doc.html#booleanVarRow">booleanVar</a>
```

But rst doesn't automatically assign ids to tr rows, so I was wondering if there is a way to manually assign it. Something like

```
 * - .. _booleanVarRow:  booleanVar
```

to yield the a result like:

```
<tr id="booleanVarRow"> ... </tr>
```

or even

```
<tr>
    <td><span id="booleanVarRow"></span>booleanVar</td>
</tr>
```

would do the job

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. This is the right syntax:

```
.. list-table::
      :widths: 5, 32
      :header-rows: 1

      * - Name
        - Default Value

          .. _numVarRow:
      * - numVar
        - 515

          .. _stringVarRow:
      * - stringVar
        - "Hello World"

          .. _arrayVarRow:
      * - arrayVar
        - [1,9,42,14,10,11,-1]

          .. _booleanVarRow:
      * - booleanVar
        - true

          .. _objectVarRow:
      * - objectVar
        - {"keyA":"valueA","keyNum":3}

          .. _nullVarRow:
      * - nullVar
        - null
```

You just have to make sure the anchor ( .. _something: ) is spaced to be aligned with the row